# TerminateProcess() doesn't close opened windows straight away

Tags: windows, createprocess

I'm using the *CreateProcess* API with the **CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE** option, since I want the app to be opened in a new window.
When I call *TerminateProcess*, it doesn't close the window right away, but rather with a delay. Is it possible to somehow force it to close the window straight away?

I'm currently running on Windows7 64bit, but the program I'm working on shouldn't be dependent on the WIN version.

I wanted to use **CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE** so that the main window won't be hijacked by the new application.

Comment: Well, you could hunt down the window handle and kill it, but why do you want to do this? It sounds like the system is working as designed.

Comment: TerminateProcess is a rather heavy-handed way of shutting down a process. If you have that option, [posting a WM_QUIT message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945(v=vs.85).aspx) to the application's main window handle is a cleaner approach.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It's a console process. And anyway, you can't use `PostQuitMessage` on another process. That operates on the calling thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Oops - you are right, I somehow missed the part about it being a console app. For a UI app he would need to use PostThreadMessage message, which does work, but he would then need to identify the thread id first.

Comment: Is the application creating subprocesses?  Console windows don't close until all associated processes exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
TCHAR szCommand[MAX_PATH];
_sntprintf_s(szCommand, MAX_PATH, _T("%s"), _T("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"));
DWORD res = CreateProcess(NULL, szCommand, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
                          CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, 
                          NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, NULL);
```

No delays in termination process.

[image]

Try use [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to figure out where delay occur in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the info and useful APP. I haven't found anything so far, but I think I need to investigate my Application a bit, maybe its entering a sleep or waits, and the termination is not right away. Perhaps I need to signal it to wake up or something similar.

Comment: I tried checking the status of the process after closing it (Calling **TerminateProcess**, and even after calling **CloseHandle**), using **GetExitCodeProcess** and I got exit code of 0, meaning that the the process has been closed properly (I guess). But the newly opened window is still there, and is closed after a delay.